# Mysql IF EXISTS THEN

Tags: mysql

So--i'm having an issue with my code. I'm testing it directly in the console and getting an "syntax error"

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_inventory WHERE resource_id = '6'
>   AND uid ='1') T' at line 1

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_inventory WHERE resource_id = '6' AND uid ='1') 
THEN UPDATE user_inventory SET resource_count = resource_count+1 WHERE resource_id = 6 AND uid = 1
ELSE INSERT INTO user_inventory(uid, resource_id, resource_count) VALUES (1, 6, 1);
```

I've never used the IF EXISTS clause before... So I'm not sure what i've done wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The SQL [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/if.html) statement can only be used within a [stored program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-views.html).  You can't use it within a generic SQL context as you have attempted.

However, you do not need to use `IF` here:

1. Define a suitable uniqueness constraint on your `user_inventory` table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE user_inventory ADD UNIQUE (uid, resource_id)
   ```
2. Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

   ```
   INSERT INTO user_inventory
     (uid, resource_id, resource_count)
   VALUES
     (1, 6, 1)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     resource_count = resource_count + 1
   ```

Comment: Okay. thank you. this isn't a viable option for what i need to be done, so i'll have to find another method.

Comment: @user3277023: If you could explain why it "*isn't a viable option*", then someone might be able to suggest a suitable alternative.